# Efficiency of Parabolic Trough

Tags: energy, efficiency, solar-energy

I just started learning this in class and am not understanding how to answer.. A parabolic trough has an active area of 18.1 m2, and produces 2960 W of power. The average solar power that falls on the active area of the parabolic trough is 1195 W/m2. Calculate the efficiency of the parabolic trough.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the power per square meter for the trough from the given data (18.1square meters, 2960Watts) then divide that by the average solar power per meter.

---

Since this is obviously homework, hints only.